# If statment in bash with multiple groups?

Tags: bash, travis-ci

What I want is

```
if((TRAVIS_BRANCH != "master") || (TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == true)
```

How do I do this in bash? I think this is the closest, but it still doesn't work

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" != "master" ] || ["$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" &&  "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "true"]
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? It looks like you have at least one syntax error in there.

Comment: When the first check `[ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" != "master" ]` fails, guess what `"$TRAVIS_BRANCH"` will be: You do not need to check that in your second check.

Answer (score 1):

Put spaces around your command names (`[` is a command name), don't try to use `&&` or `||` within a single `[` command.

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" != "master" ] || { [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "true"]; }
```

However, you *can* use `&&` or `||` inside of `[[ ]]`, and also have less need to quote there:

```
if [[ $TRAVIS_BRANCH != master ]] || [[ $TRAVIS_BRANCH = master && $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST = true ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure the `[` and `]` characters are surrounded by spaces
- Double equals works in Bash, but is not POSIX compatible
- You have to use `-a`, not `&&`, inside `[`
- Because of the [difficulty in working out the precedence rules](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Grouping_Statements) in shell code it's recommended not to use more than one boolean operator per line of code
- It's recommended to use `[[` rather than `[` in Bash

Result:

```
is_master_pull_request() {
    [[ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]] && [[ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "true" ]]
}
if [[ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" != "master" ]] || is_master_pull_request
```

Comment: The `-a` syntax is deprecated by POSIX for good cause. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html -- you'll note that all uses of `test` with 4 or more arguments (and yours has seven) has results unspecified by the standard. (Arguments such as `(` and `)` could be parsed as grouping operators rather than data in this context, leading to ambiguous situations).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" != "master" ] || [[ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" && "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "true" ]]; then
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. I prefer `=` to `==` for stylistic reasons inside `[[ ]]` (as it's the POSIX-compliant operator), but `==` is perfectly allowable.